# How to get all the results if variable is empty string

Tags: mongodb, meteor

If **searchString** have some text it works OK, but if string is empty it returns nothing, how to get whole the results?

```
find({ $text: { $search: searchString }});
```

Added:

```
Meteor.publish("messages", function(freeText){
    return Messages.find({ $text: { $search: freeText }});
});
```

I using a variable to get messages by "free text", and need a case for empty string

Comment: Can you show your document with the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to explicitly check for that and use a different query in that case:

```js
Meteor.publish("messages", function(freeText){
    if (freeText) {
        return Messages.find({ $text: { $search: freeText }});
    } else {
        return Messages.find();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thought that there is some attribute or something like '*' sign that can help with. Or some $ne: "". But just can't find it.